# Unexpected behavior of QGIS appears when I load a raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a small plugin for QGis which is collecting paratemters from gui for URL request to load raster layes (**WMS**).

Example:

```
 urlWithParams = self.get_values()
 mylayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, (self.dockwidget.txt_layer_name.text()), "wms")
 QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mylayer, False)
 self.root.insertLayer(0, mylayer)
```

Everything is working fine, but the unexpected behavior of QGis appears, 
if I have a vector layer loaded and then I load the raster layer, the zoom in shifts to the magnifier, then I have to *lock and unlock* the scale to work with scale.

Why it switch to magnifier and if there is a way through the python script to `'force' to work with the scale` instead of the magnifier after loading the raster layer?

[image]

Its happening something like that wheel action is conected to the
magnifier instead of scale after loading raster layer, **how to connect wheel action  with scale**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone is going to have the same problem, in the end the solution was very simple:

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().setScaleLocked(False)
```

> **setScaleLocked**
>
> ```
> void QgsMapCanvas::setScaleLocked (bool isLocked)
> ```
>
> Lock the scale (set True), so zooming can be performed using magnication, or
>   oposite set False so zooming can be performed using scale.
>
> Since QGIS 2.16